# How does the body respond to blood donation; are there any possible risks?

Tags: human-biology, hematology, medicine, blood-circulation

Can blood donation cause any harm to the donor? I have been told so, but cannot find any references supporting this claim. I have also learned that our body will replace the lost fluids within 24 hours and the RBCs within weeks. Can blood donation still cause health issues for our body?

This is not a personal medication question, and I mainly want to know how the body responds to blood loss and what mechanisms that monitor the altered levels of blood volume? To me, it would also be unethical by medical doctors to withhold the possible risks of blood donation to prospective donors, but it might also be seen as unethical to discourage a person willing to donate blood from doing so, so there might be a conflict of interest here.

Comment: If this is not a personal medical question, you should remove all references to yourself. Also, medical ethics specifically prohibits hiding information from patients.

Comment: @canadianer:I have removed

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to know if blood donations are harmful for the donor?

Comment: @Chris: Yes thats what I am looking for !

Comment: Tried to clarify your question. Feel free to roll-back if you disagree.

Comment: @fileunderwater: Thank you, now it looks like a question !

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that doctors hide risks from donors? Have you ever donated blood?

Comment: @chris The poster was encouraged to remove all personal details, so the part saying that he/she is a donor has been removed (see edit history). The last sentence on ethics is secondary to the question though, and I thought about removing it.

Comment: @Chris: I haven't concluded that doctors hide the risks, I rather inquired about it. Yes I have donated blood.

Comment: As biology and medical science have some common relationships, but medical ethics have nothing to do with biology. But this question bears biological origin and question about ethics is a bonus :)

Comment: found on internet: After blood donation, it generally takes a day or two to replenish the fluid volume in the body and three months for the regeneration of red cells to donate more blood. The total amount of blood circulating in our body's cardiovascular system is about 5 liters. Of this amount, only about 350 ml. is bled from the body during blood donation. The human body replenishes this amount of blood donated within about 48 to 72 hours of donation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer below directly (and solely) addresses what I think is the main gist of the question: Are there any adverse effects on one's physiology as a direct result of donating blood?

Blood donation, at the amounts typically taken (200~500mls), will not harm you. A healthy human being produces approximately 100,000,000,000 (one hundred billion) NEW hematopoietic cells DAILY to replenish short-lived blood cells and platelets. All of these ultimately derive from the hematopoietic stem cells residing in the bone marrow within one's long bones.

As you can appreciate, with such a huge amount of turnover daily, the body is constantly churning out new blood cells. Thus, any depletion in blood cells one will experience as a result of blood donation is a fraction of what will be lost normally in daily homeostasis anyway and thus will not affect a healthy individual.

And then there are the knock-on benefits suggested by epidemiological studies, some of which are alluded in this layman article: http://news.health.com/2014/06/13/4-unexpected-benefits-of-donating-blood/

[source: I'm a hematologist]

Comment: How much amount of blood loss is considered as fatal ?

Comment: If you lose > 40% of blood volume (~2.5 L for a 75kg healthy adult male), it is most likely fatal. However, one will probably start to feel the effects (classed as hypvolemia) after >15% blood loss. As you can see, even at maximal amounts of blood donated, it is a tiny fraction of total blood volume and certainly not going to be fatal. You seem to be excessively concerned about a safe procedure that has been routinely done for over 5 decades. The biggest harm is not from donating, but from NOT donating!

Comment: Your answer and comment seems awesome and I am glad that you are worried about by excessive concerns :)

Comment: @Cantona Collar What on earth? You can start feeling the effects of blood loss (hypovolemia) after 15% blood loss? At 2.5L for a healthy adult male 15% is 375ml and you say they take 200-500mls. Seems to me from these numbers they take so much blood it approaches the quantity of blood loss which is approaching hypovolemia already.

Comment: @Zebrafish, I think you need to re-read what I wrote before typing. The total volume of blood in an average healthy human is ~5L (https://www.webcitation.org/mainframe.php)

Comment: @Cantona's Collar Right, I misread your comment. So taking 200 - 500mls of blood from a healthy adult male is taking between 4 and 10 per cent of their blood. And you say the effects of hypovolemia can be felt at 15% loss. That still seems close to the threshold to me.