# Can someone donate antibodies?

Tags: antibody, coronavirus

Consider the following scenario:

- Person A has been infected with some virus (for example, SARS-CoV-2)
- Person A has recovered

From this scenario, I assume Person A has managed to develop antibodies for SARS-CoV-2. If so:

1. For how long, after recovery, would Person A have antibodies for the virus running in their blood?
2. If Person A donates blood to Person B, would Person B have better responses against the virus, by using  the antibodies received along the blood from Person A? *(assuming the donation is successful without issues)*
3. Is there any paper / study building upon this idea for combating SARS-CoV-2?

Notes:

- I am not expecting exact quantitative answers to these questions. I just want basic understanding for reasons this could or could not work.

Comment: SE Biology is a question and answer site — not a discussion site or a site for floating ideas. It is concerned with the mechanisms of biological processes, not medical or social aspects of biology. I therefore think  that your question on dealing with the coronavirus outbreak is off-topic here. You are advised to consult more appropriate reputable sources for such information, some of which are listed [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/information-about-coronaviruses/4036#4036).

Comment: @David Sorry about that. Is there another SE in which this topic would have been more appropriate? Also, I have to point out that your comment about SE being "not a discussion site or a site for floating ideas" is also off-topic, since I know that very well and did not call for any discussion and asked directly answerable questions, to which in fact I answered myself.

Comment: You could try SE Medical Sciences. However there is a very good article in today’s Financial Times (27 March) on the subject. I’m a subscriber to the paper edition, but you may find it on line. You’re probably entitled to three free articles. If you are not familiar with the FT do not be put off by its name. It is the foremost British serious newspaper (with US and European offices). In times like these you need to know where to find reliable information.

Comment: @David Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, each question should be posted separately — this improves the chances that you will get answers for each question and makes the answers more accessible for future users. In addition, each of those questions must be appropriate for this site! ——— We also encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the body respond to blood donation; are there any possible risks?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/30822/how-does-the-body-respond-to-blood-donation-are-there-any-possible-risks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question 1

> [...] antibodies [...] can last anywhere between a few weeks to a few months. The antibodies themselves though (which are proteins) definitely don't last forever (like all proteins). Eventually certain suppressor cells kill off plasma cells after the response has taken its course, and all that remains are a few memory cells, which are reactivated again should the pathogen invade the body in the future.

[Source](https://forums.studentdoctor.net/threads/do-antibodies-remain-in-the-blood-after-the-pathogen-is-gone.1071622/post-15237231)

## Question 2 and 3

Yes.

- [Here is an article from Johns Hopkins University](https://hub.jhu.edu/2020/03/13/covid-19-antibody-sera-arturo-casadevall/).
- [Here is a paper by Arturo Casadevall and Liise-anne Pirofski](https://www.jci.org/articles/view/138003) mentioned in the above article and published on the Journal of Clinical Investigation on March 13, 2020.

---

*Fun fact: I was about to say in the question that I tried to research but didn't find anything. But I decided to make a last attempt, and actually found the answers...*

Comment: Please note that while answering your own questions is completely fine, you should first fix (where possible) and/or delete the problematic sections of your question. ——— In addition, link only answers (what you provide for your second and third questions) are not acceptable — answers should not require other users to follow links (links also often break rendering the answer completely useless in the future). Please consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thanks! 